# Has the spin and parity of the Higgs boson been experimentally confirmed?

Tags: quantum-spin, bosons, elementary-particles, higgs, parity

I read in a newspaper that the Higgs boson might be the new boson but that this was not confirmed, because we don't know its properties, e.g. its spin or parity. Now I see it confirmed that it is the Higgs boson, but, really, is it true?

I don't have access to the journal Physical Review D, and I can't find a clear detailed explanation of the claim or the alternative possibilities. Could someone explain it for this curious layman?

Comment: they detected higgs boson                                         spin paridad ?

Comment: StackExchange isn't really the site to ask this kind of thing. Use Google search. It has many answers. Also, you use the pronoun "he" and "his" without actually naming anyone in your question, so it's impossible for readers to figure out who you're even talking about.

Comment: I agree that the question is poorly worded, but is it such a bad question?  He wants to know about spin and parity measurements of the Higgs. Why isn't that appropriate for SE?

Comment: I think what @innisfree says is reasonable. This question may be salvageable through editing. Although there's also a good chance it's a duplicate of something. (Not sure what, at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the paper [Evidence for the spin-0 nature of the Higgs boson using ATLAS data](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1432). We don't have enough data to rule out the possibility the particle recently discovered might be spin 2, but it looks very unlikely. The data we have gives us about 98% confidence that the new particle is spin 0 with positive parity - i.e. it's the Higgs boson.

Comment: Moreover, the branching fractions seem to be just right for a Higgs boson.